# Not able to install HCatalog Connector in Vertica

Tags: vertica

I copied all hadoop files in

```
/opt/vertica/packages/hcat/lib
```

now when I run

```
./hcatUtil --verifyJars --hcatLibPath=/opt/vertica/packages/hcat
```

I see

```
Summary
-------
Found 27 out of 27 required JARs
Found 5 out of 5 optional Hive SerDe related JARs
Found 2 out of 2 optional native libraries, 5 files in total
Looking at [/opt/vertica/packages/hcat] for configuration files
Found configuration file [cli.xml]
Found configuration file [data-manipulation-statements.xml]
Found configuration file [joins.xml]
Found configuration file [reflect.xml]
Found configuration file [index.xml]
Found configuration file [hdfs-site.xml]
Found configuration file [yarn-site.xml]
Found configuration file [ssl-client.xml]
Found configuration file [core-site.xml]
Found configuration file [project.xml]
Found configuration file [mapred-site.xml]
Found configuration file [var_substitution.xml]
Found configuration file [hive-site.xml]
Found configuration file [working_with_bucketed_tables.xml]
```

But when I run

```
vsql
\cd /opt/vertica/packages/hcat/ddl
\i install.sql
```

I get an error

```
sql:install.sql:13: NOTICE 6564: Found Hadoop configuration files in dependency paths. If any of the configuration files is changed, please re-install HCatalog connector library with modified configuration files
CREATE LIBRARY
vsql:install.sql:16: ROLLBACK 3399: Failure in UDx RPC call InvokeSetExecContext(): Error in User Defined Object [VHCatSource], error code: 0
Couldn't instantiate class com.vertica.hcatalogudl.HCatalogSplitsNoOpSourceFactory
vsql:install.sql:17: ROLLBACK 2059: Source with specified name and parameters does not exist: VHCatSource
vsql:install.sql:18: ROLLBACK 3399: Failure in UDx RPC call InvokeSetExecContext(): Error in User Defined Object [VHCatParser], error code: 0
Couldn't instantiate class com.vertica.hcatalogudl.HCatalogSplitsParserFactory
vsql:install.sql:19: ROLLBACK 2059: Parser with specified name and parameters does not exist: VHCatParser
vsql:install.sql:20: ROLLBACK 3472: Function with same name and number of parameters already exists: get_webhcat_host
vertica=>
```

I googled and found this thread
 
    https://community.dev.hpe.com/t5/Vertica-Forum/hcatalog-connector/td-p/222733

So I copied the contents of `/etc/hadoop/conf` directory from one of the Hadoop nodes to all the nodes of my vertica cluster.

next I did

```
\i /opt/vertica/packages/hcat/ddl/uninstall.sql
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET JavaClassPathSuffixForUDx='/etc/hadoop-hdfs-conf/';
\i /opt/vertica/packages/hcat/ddl/install.sql
```

But this does not solve the problem. I still get the same error message.

EDIT::

I did more re-search on the problem and I feel that HP has shipped the wrong vertica-hcatalogudl.jar with the product. This is why this doesn't work for anyone else.

If I do

```
create or replace library public.VHCatalogLib as '/opt/vertica/packages/hcat/lib2/vertica-hcatalogudl.jar' DEPENDS '/opt/vertica/packages/hcat/lib/*.*' language 'java';
```

I can see the following objects are installed by this libary

```
SELECT * FROM USER_LIBRARY_MANIFEST WHERE lib_name = 'VHCatalogLib';
 schema_name |   lib_name   |      lib_oid      |                     obj_name                     |    obj_type     | arg_types | return_type
-------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------
 public      | VHCatalogLib | 45035996371219906 | com.vertica.hcatalogudl.WebHCatConfLoaderFactory | Scalar Function |           | Varchar
(1 row)
```

but when I read the source code of install.sql which comes with the hcatalog connector. it says

```
CREATE SOURCE public.VHCatSource as LANGUAGE 'java'  name 'com.vertica.hcatalogudl.HCatalogSplitsNoOpSourceFactory' library public.VHCatalogLib;
GRANT EXECUTE ON SOURCE public.VHCatSource() TO PUBLIC;
CREATE PARSER public.VHCatParser as LANGUAGE 'java'  name 'com.vertica.hcatalogudl.HCatalogSplitsParserFactory' library public.VHCatalogLib;
GRANT EXECUTE ON PARSER public.VHCatParser() TO PUBLIC;
```

But the library never installed

- com.vertica.hcatalogudl.HCatalogSplitsNoOpSourceFactory
- com.vertica.hcatalogudl.HCatalogSplitsParserFactory

This is why we get an error

Couldn't instantiate class com.vertica.hcatalogudl.HCatalogSplitsParserFactory

Because this because they ship the wrong vertica-hcatalogudl.jar file.

I am pretty sure somewhere inside HP vertica team there is a vertica-hcatalogudl.jar file which has all the 3 objects required to make the installation succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by the help of HP support. The results are here

https://community.dev.hpe.com/t5/Vertica-Forum/HP-has-shipped-the-wrong-version-of-vertica-hcatalogudl-jar-with/m-p/233761#U233761

The gist of the problem was that I was using Vertica 7.1.2-2 and Cloudera 5.4.1 and they are not compatible with each other.

Once I upgraded my Vertica instance to 7.2 ... things worked out pretty smoothly.